# What is best way to practice selenium using webdriver as a beginner

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am  a software test engineer with almost 4 yrs of exp in Manual testing,
Want to switch to automation testing.
What is best way to practice selenium using webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic steps that I would suggest having been in your shoes in the past.

1. If you have no coding experience, go to [Codecademy Learn Java](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java)
   and go through the course to get the basics of programming.
2. Follow this [tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/selenium/posts/selenium-tutorial-with-java)
3. Read up on Page Object Model [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html)
4. Take a test from your current job and try to automate it
5. Remember that Google and Stack Overflow are your friends.
6. TAKE YOUR TIME! This is a process, the more time you spend on each step the better you will be in the long run